# Return only specific fields in REST Query in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: rest, sharepoint-2010

I have a list/library with lets say 20 columns(fields) and in my REST Query I only want 2 fields to be returned, instead of all 20. How do I accomplish this:

Current Query:

```
http://server/site/collection/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/MyList?$filter=Name eq 'Username' and SomeField ne null&$orderby=DateFrom desc&select=field1,field2
```

But this always returns all 20 fields. Isn't $select supposed to return only the fields I'm giving in the URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

doh, I just checked the URL again and noticed I forgot the '$' in the select statement. So it should be:

```
http://server/site/collection/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/MyList?$filter=Name eq 'Username' and SomeField ne null&$orderby=DateFrom desc&$select=field1,field2
```